# Jquery .hasClass() method not working on dom click event check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input box with class `use-keyboard-input`. I want to have DOM event fire in all click events except when the input box is clicked

I did:

```
$('*').click(function(event) {


    if ($(this).hasClass('use-keyboard-input') == false){
        console.log(`pressing outside the box`)

        keyboardHidden = false
        $('.keyboard--hidden').each(()=>{
            keyboardHidden = true          
        })


        if (keyboardHidden == false){     //If keyboard is not hidden
            // if (this !== $(".keyboard")) { 
                Keyboard.close();
                console.log(`Close the keyboard`)
            // }
        }
    }


});
```

However, even when I click inside the input box with class `use-keyboard-input`, I get the console message

`console.log("pressing outside the box")`

Comment: Events bubble up the DOM tree to parent elements.

Comment: as @Pointy mentioned, events bubble up the DOM hierarchy. So click on the input box also fires click event on all of its ancestor elements. Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent event bubbling up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [**`Event.stopPropagation()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) which will prevent further propagation of the current event in the ***capturing*** and ***bubbling*** phases.

**Demo:**

```js
$('*').click(function(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();
  if ($(this).hasClass('use-keyboard-input') == false){
    console.log(`pressing outside the box`)

    keyboardHidden = false
    $('.keyboard--hidden').each(()=>{
      keyboardHidden = true          
    })


    if (keyboardHidden == false){     //If keyboard is not hidden
      console.log(`Close the keyboard`)
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Container
  <input class="use-keyboard-input"/>
</div>
```